# Google drive get recently uploaded files

Tags: time, google-drive

I have a question about using Google Drive and want to ask for any trick, or any API.
Concept: I and my teammates are using a same Google Drive folder. Everyday, he upload many files to some folders in the shared folder. I wanna check which files he just uploaded to the Drive, but the `Activity` tab of Google Drive seem useless when it is not listing all the recently uploaded files.

How can I know which recently files has been uploaded into the Drive inside the shared folder (include children folders)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently tried this command line google drive tool [gdrive](https://github.com/gdrive-org/gdrive)

With this tool, you can achieve your goal quite easily, a sample command would be:

```
gdrive-windows-x64.exe list --absolute --name-width 0
```

This command displays the top 100 files created lately with their absolute path. You can then process the result of this command even more with other tools if needed.

Comment: So I can only see the last 100 files created in entire the drive and the folder must be created on my own? And I must process the result to get better view? Seem limited. Look like I have no other choice, thank you very much.

Comment: By default 100 files, you can see more if you want to, like most command line apps it has a lot of switches. I believe it displays everything in your drive no matter who owns it.